# Sorting images with exiftool while maintaining current directory structure (kind of)

Tags: exiftool, windows-7

An example of starting directory structure,

```
\best camping trip ever\ <-parent directory referred below
      \from my cell phone\
      \from my camera\
      \Johns camera\
      \Cindys camera\
```

Now if I run this command,

```
exiftool "-directory<EXIF:DateTimeOriginal" -d %Y%m%d -r .
```

while being in parent directory exiftool will make folders based on dates and will sort the images in them. I would prefer to do something like this,

```
\20151020\from my cell phone\
         \from my camera\
         ...
\20151021\from my cell phone\
         \...
         \Johns camera\
         ...
```

you get the point. To keep the original structure, so I have an idea from what device and/or person images in question came from.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parent directory is your current directory and you can use this command:
`exiftool "-directory<EXIF:DateTimeOriginal" -d "%Y%m%d/%%d" -r .`

Example, given this `tree \f` for the current directory, then running the above command, gives the end result:

```
X:\!temp\test>tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Data
Volume serial number is 00000200 1CFF:E96C
X:.
│   20140404_040404.jpg
│   20150303_030303.jpg
│   
└───2010
    └───12
        └───25
                Test.jpg


X:\!temp\test>exiftool  -d "%Y%m%d/%%d" "-directory<DateTimeOriginal"  -r .
    4 directories scanned
    3 directories created
    3 image files updated

X:\!temp\test>tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume Data
Volume serial number is 00000200 1CFF:E96C
X:.
│   
├───2010
│   └───12
│       └───25
├───20101225
│   └───2010
│       └───12
│           └───25
│                   Test.jpg
│                   
├───20140404
│       20140404_040404.jpg
│       
└───20150303
        20150303_030303.jpg
```

Test.jpg still retains the 2010/12/25 path under the new directory.  Also note that the original directory is not removed.

The addition of `%%d` escapes the last `%d` so it is interpreted as the directory from the [`-w`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut) option instead of the date from the `-d` option.

This command will result in different results if you aren't using the current directory.  If the current directory is on a different drive than the target directory, then you will most likely get an error as it tries to append the target directory name onto the current directory, something like `c:\CurrentDir\D:\TargetDir`.  If this needs to be done, then look into the %d options under the [`-w`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut) option.